# How to use a new Windows Terminal app for SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, console, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) app is advertised as a central hub for all terminal work, so I'm interested in a way to bring my SSH connections into it and replace ancient PuTTY.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a `commandline` field in your [profile configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-general#command-line) to initiate an SSH connection on tab creation.

Step-by-step guide:

1. Ensure you have an SSH client (try to connect to the server from a `Command Prompt` tab). [@dhgouveia2's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029292/3399377) details this step.
2. Open **Settings** (Ctrl+,)
3. Find the `"list"` array in the `"profiles"` object
4. Find a `Command Prompt` profile (`"commandline": "cmd.exe"`)
5. Duplicate the profile (copy-paste the whole object, watch for the comma between objects)
6. Change the `"guid"` value to a new GUID (for example, [from here](https://www.guidgen.com/))
7. Change the `commandline` value to `"commandline" : "ssh me@my-server -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"` (use your own connection command).
8. Change the profile's `"name"`
9. Add an `"icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png"` item to use a Tux icon (default icons are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/master/src/cascadia/CascadiaPackage/ProfileIcons))
10. You should have something like this:

    ```json
    {
        "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
        "profiles":
        {
            "list":
            [
                // ...
                {
                    "guid": "{1d43c510-93e8-4960-a18b-e432641e0930}",
                    "name": "ssh my-server",
                    "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png",
                    "commandline": "ssh me@my-server -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    ```
11. Save the configuration and enjoy the new item in the **New Tab** drop-down.

Comment: If you wanted to use WSL instead of Powershell for connecting, you can use "debian run ssh me@my-server -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" instead.

I'm using Debian as my WSL install, this could differ per WSL OS.

Comment: I was using commadLine instead of commandline couldn't understand what I was doing wrong omg.

Answer (score 33):

You can use native ssh client from Windows 10,

## From powershell

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

# This should return the following output:

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

## Install the OpenSSH Client

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

## It should return the following output:

```
Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

## Uninstall the OpenSSH Client

```
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

## Add the hosts to your ssh config file

From your home folder, go to the .ssh/config file, the folder may not exist if the ssh application has not been used, so it will be necessary to create it on you home folder

> C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh

[@Damo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6997335/damo) post a very good documentation about the ssh config.

e.g `config`

```
Host test
    User test
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

## Windows Terminal

Similar to the [@Himura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3399377/himura) instructions, but instead of using "bash.exe" you will using "ssh.exe".

For connection to the remote host, you can use the hostname from the.ssh/config file e.g `ssh.exe test`, if you don't want to use a config file, you can use the user@ip `ssh.exe test@127.0.0.1` and the password dialog will be promt

- Edit your `profile.json` from the settings on Windows Terminal,
- Duplicate a profile
- Change the "guid" value to a new GUID
- Change the commandline value with ssh.exe, e.g `"commandline" : "ssh.exe test"`
- Change the profile's "name"

e.g

> C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config

```
Host vagrant
    Hostname 127.0.0.1
    Port 2222
    User vagrant
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vagrant.key
```

> profile.json

```
    ...
    {
        "acrylicOpacity" : 0.75,
        "closeOnExit" : true,
        "colorScheme" : "One Half Dark",
        "commandline" : "ssh.exe vagrant",
        "cursorColor" : "#FFFFFF",
        "cursorShape" : "bar",
        "fontFace" : "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline",
        "fontSize" : 10,
        "guid" : "{1777cdf0-b2c4-5a63-a204-1111f349ea7c}",
        "historySize" : 9001,
        "icon" : "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{9acb9455-ca41-5af7-950f-6bca1bc9722f}.png",
        "name" : "Vagrant",
        "padding" : "0, 0, 0, 0",
        "snapOnInput" : true,
        "startingDirectory" : "%USERPROFILE%",
        "useAcrylic" : true
  }
  ....
```

If you want to set the new entry as default, search for the `defaultProfile` key

```
....
   "globals" : 
    {
        "alwaysShowTabs" : true,
        "copyOnSelect" : false,
        "defaultProfile" : "{1777cdf0-b2c4-5a63-a204-1111f349ea7c}",
        "initialCols" : 120,
        "initialRows" : 30,
....
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stay in the terminal and easily manage all your ssh connections inside WSL then i would recommend using the built in ssh config management in the [ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) command.

Basically you put all your different ssh configurations in to the file [~/.ssh/config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)

There is a good post documenting the basic use of this [here](https://shapeshed.com/manage-ssh-connections-with-a-ssh-config-file/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a machine on Google Compute Engine using Windows Terminal, you can write a script to replace the default command and use ssh instead of putty.exe. More details [here](https://superuser.com/a/1558617/33754).